# c++ get value from memory a process

Tags: c++11, memory

I'm trying to get the int value of a processes' memory address.

I have been able to write to the memory address can't read the memory address value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


int main(void) {

    int nVal = 40000;

    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, "Crusader");
    if(hWnd == 0){
        cerr << "Could not find window." << endl;
    } else {
        DWORD PID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &PID);
        HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, PID);

        if(!hProc) {
            cerr << "Cannot open process." << endl;
        } else {
            int buffer = 0;
            int stat = WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)0x0115FCF8, &nVal, (DWORD)sizeof(nVal), NULL);
            SIZE_T NumberOfBytesToRead = sizeof(buffer); //this is equal to 4
            SIZE_T NumberOfBytesActuallyRead;


            int stat2 = ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)0x0115FCF8, &buffer, NumberOfBytesToRead, &NumberOfBytesActuallyRead);
            std:cout<< *stat2;

           /* if(stat > 0){
                clog << "Memory written to process." << endl;
            } else {
                cerr << "Memory couldn't be written to process." << endl;
            }
*/
            CloseHandle(hProc);

            cin.get();

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can assign a value to the memory address, but reading the memory address returns 1.
How can i get the value of the address

Comment: You're aware that the value is returned into `buffer`, not `stat2`, right?

Answer (score 0):

stat and stat2 represent the return value of the Read/Write ProcessMemory calls, these are used in error checking.  You appear to be thinking they are the values of the addresses you're trying to read and write.

Assuming your target process is x86, you're compiling for x86, you're running as admin and all your addresses are correct then just change that last line to:

`std:cout<< buffer;`

This should output the integer representation of the data in 0x0115FCF8

If 0x0115FCF8 is data, not code this should work fine.  If it's code, the page will not have write permissions and you will have to change the page permission with VirtualProtectEx to include WRITE.